# Suspected parsing error in code using exit function

Tags: python

When I run this piece of code, I want the program to end after 'EASTER EGG' is printed.
Instead the code breaks in try, except and prints 'file not found'. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

```
finp=input('File name: ')
try:
    if finp=='easter egg':
        print('EASTER EGG')
        exit()
    else:
       file=open(finp,'r')
except:
    print('File not found. Please enter a valid file name.')
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**exit()** is raising [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception.

Thus the interpreter goes in the except block. The moment it gets in except block, it prints that message. And the program ends.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#exit) for docs referral.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `exit()` works by throwing an exception.

You should normally specify an exception type to catch in all `except` clauses, like this:

```
finp = input('File name: ')
try:
    if finp == 'easter egg':
        print('EASTER EGG')
        exit()
    else:
       file = open(finp,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:     # Added Exception type here
    print('File not found. Please enter a valid file name.')
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the try/except block to encapsule only the file operations.

```
finp=input('File name: ')
if finp=='easter egg':
    print('EASTER EGG')
else:
    try:
        file = open(finp,'r')
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print('File not found. Please enter a valid file name.')
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

finp = input('File name: ')
try:
    if finp == 'easter egg':
        print('EASTER EGG')
        os._exit(1)
    else:
       file = open(finp,'r')
except:
    print('File not found. Please enter a valid file name.')
    os._exit(1)
```